# Reduce dataframe rows with filter by ID

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
      import pandas as pd

      dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'ID_Sensor': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
                      'Type': ['Analog', 'Analog', 'Analog', 'Dig', 'Dig', 'Analog', 'Analog'],
                      'Value': [100, 200, 300, 1, 0, 400, 500]})
```

I would like to keep only the first line of each of the sensor identifiers. 
I tried to use the head () function, but it only returns the first line:

```
      dataframe.head(1)
```

My output:

```
      ID_Sensor    Type     Value
            1     Analog     100
```

Desired output:

```
     ID_Sensor  Type    Value
        1       Analog  100
        2        Dig     1
        3       Analog  400
```

Comment: drop_duplicates ?

Comment: The lines are not duplicated. Evolve columns with different values.

Comment: Did you try ? `df.drop_duplicates(['ID_Sensor','Type'])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and chain [.first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html)

```
dataframe.groupby(['ID_Sensor','Type'])['Value'].first()
```

Comment: How do you return in dataframe format?

Comment: If that's what you want, then use drop duplicates. Reference to the drop duplicate answers.

Comment: You can method chain `.to_frame()` to @wwnde's solution. This will change the answer from a series object to a dataframe.

Comment: I managed to solve using:
df = dataframe.groupby('ID_Sensor', as_index = False)['Type', 'Value'].first()